# Odd behavior of the reactiveValuesToList() function in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I recently discovered the `reactiveValuesToList()` function, which I use to keep track of the inputs in my apps because some inputs are created dynamically. Following is a simple example to illustrate an odd behavior of the function.

My app has 3 components:

- `checkBoxGroupInput()`: with 3 choices
- `uiOutput()`: to dynamically create numeric inputs based on the boxes checked by the user.
- `textOutput()`: that displays the IDs of all the input UI's in the web app.

Here is the script of the simple app described above:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # The user selects team names
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "team", label = "Select team", choices = letters[1:3]),

  br(),

  # Placeholder for the dynamic numeric inputs that are created based on the selected team names
  uiOutput(outputId = "dynUI1"),

  # Text output for the names of the input UIs in the shiny app
  textOutput(outputId = "uiIds")  
)

server <- function(input, output){

  # These are the input IDs of the dynamically created UI in dynUI1
  uiNames <- c(a = "id_a", b = "id_b", c = "id_c")

  output$dynUI1 <- renderUI({
    if(length(input$team) == 0){
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      lapply(1:length(input$team), function(i){
        inputname <- paste0("Points: team ", input$team[i])
        numericInput(inputId = uiNames[input$team[i]], label = inputname, value = 1, min = 1, max = 5)
      })
    }
  })

  output$uiIds <- renderText({
    names(reactiveValuesToList(input))
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

At the launch of the app, the `textOuput` displays `team` and rightfully so, because that's the only input element in the app. When `a` is checked, for instance, the `textOutput` then displays `team` and `id_a` because a new input element has just been added to the app. The odd behavior is this: when `a` is unchecked, even though the dynamic input element disappears from the app, its id remains in the `textOutput`.

Why is that? How can I correct it?

Please copy, paste the code and run it to see it for yourself.

Comment: Have you tried to use `insertUI` and `removeUI` from Shiny 0.14 to create the dynamic UI? And if yes does that solve the problem?

Comment: @warmoverflow I have not. Will give it a try and let you know. Thank you.